# Calculate difference between 2 timestamps using javascript

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I have to calculate the difference between 2 timestamps. Also can you please help me with conversion of a string into timestamp. Using plain javascript only. NO JQUERY.

Here's my function:

```
function clearInactiveSessions()
{
    alert("ok");
    <c:if test="${not empty pageScope.sessionView.sessionInfo}">
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        alert("curr:"+currentTime);
        var difference=new Date();
        <c:forEach items="${pageScope.sessionView.sessionInfo}" var="inactiveSession">
            var lastAccessTime = ${inactiveSession.lastUpdate};
            difference.setTime(Maths.abs(currentTime.getTime()-lastAccessTime.getTime()));
            var timediff=diff.getTime();
            alert("timediff:"+timediff);
            var mins=Maths.floor(timediff/(1000*60*60*24*60));
            alert("mins:"+mins);
            if(mins<45)
                clearSession(${item.sessionID});
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
}
```

Comment: What format is the "time stamp", ISO8601? And the non–timestamp string looks like…?

Comment: `var diff=Math.abs(date1-date2);`

Comment: @elclanrs—I think maybe there's some parsing first.

Comment: @RobG this is the format I have in the List Mon May 27 11:46:15 IST 2013. I need to convert this into a timestamp, get the difference between this and the current time in minutes.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

i am posting my own example try implement this in your code

```
function timeDifference(date1,date2) {
    var difference = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();

    var daysDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60/60/24);
    difference -= daysDifference*1000*60*60*24

    var hoursDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60/60);
    difference -= hoursDifference*1000*60*60

    var minutesDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60);
    difference -= minutesDifference*1000*60

    var secondsDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000);

    console.log('difference = ' + 
      daysDifference + ' day/s ' + 
      hoursDifference + ' hour/s ' + 
      minutesDifference + ' minute/s ' + 
      secondsDifference + ' second/s ');
}
```

Comment: what if I needed the current time in date1. Will var date1=new Date.getTime(); do the trick?

Comment: if I have a string like "Mon May 27 11:46:15 IST 2013" how can i convert it into timestamp and calculate difference in minutes between this and the current time..pleasE?

Comment: var date = new Date(Date.parse(YourstringDate.replace(/-/g, " ")));

Comment: When I use this:

var temp_date = "Mon May 27 11:46:15 IST 2013";
var lastAccessTime = new Date(Date.parse(temp_date.replace(/-/g, " "))).getTime();

alert(lastAccessTime); -> gives me NaN. Why?

Comment: format temp_date to some Date format like dd/MM/yyy or dd/MMM/yyyy and then try the same code

Answer (score 33):

Based on the approved answer:

```
function(timestamp1, timestamp2) {
    var difference = timestamp1 - timestamp2;
    var daysDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60/60/24);

    return daysDifference;
}
```

Comment: dunno why this was downvoted. if you two dates are in the ACTUAL timestamp format : E.G. `1503964800000` (which is definitely simpler to work with than crap containing maybe `/` maybe `-` and an uncertain amount of `0`s before the digits and with the three members coming sometimes with a certain arrangement sometimes another.) then is is the better, simpler answer.

Answer (score 6):

A better alternative would be using *[window.performance API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)*

```js
const startTime = window.performance.now()
setTimeout(()=>{
 const endTime = window.performance.now()
 console.log("Time Elapsed : ",endTime-startTime) // logs ~2000 milliseconds
}, 2000)
```

Update for node.js since window.performance is not available in nodejs.

```
const {performance} = require('perf_hooks');
const startTime = performance.now();

    setTimeout(()=>{
     const endTime = performance.now();
     console.log("Time Elapsed : ",endTime-startTime) // logs ~2000 milliseconds
    }, 2000)
```

Comment: If using NodeJS, here is what will be helpful


RequireJS

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436943/referenceerror-performance-is-not-defined-when-using-performance-now#50179733)


```const {performance} = require('perf_hooks');
const t0 = performance.now();```

ES6 Module

```import { performance } from 'perf_hooks';
const t0 = performance.now();```

Comment: thanks @wakqasahmed. Updated the answer with your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is Mon May 27 11:46:15 IST 2013, you can convert it to a date object by parsing the bits (assuming 3 letter English names for months, adjust as required):

```
// Convert string like Mon May 27 11:46:15 IST 2013 to date object 
function stringToDate(s) {
  s = s.split(/[\s:]+/);
  var months = {'jan':0, 'feb':1, 'mar':2, 'apr':3, 'may':4, 'jun':5, 
                'jul':6, 'aug':7, 'sep':8, 'oct':9, 'nov':10, 'dec':11};
  return new Date(s[7], months[s[1].toLowerCase()], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]);
}

alert(stringToDate('Mon May 27 11:46:15 IST 2013'));
```

Note that if you are using date strings in the same timezone, you can ignore the timezone for the sake of difference calculations. If they are in different timezones (including differences in daylight saving time), then you must take account of those differences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package.
[@ask-imon/time_diff_calc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ask-imon/time_diff_calc)

```js
// Import the function and FormatTypes - assuming they are in the same file
const { timeDiffCalc, FormatTypes } = require('@ask-imon/time_diff_calc');

// Example timestamps
const timestamp1 = "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z";
const timestamp2 = "2023-01-02T12:30:45Z";

// Calculate the difference in a specific format

// To get the difference in Milliseconds
const differenceInMilliseconds = timeDiffCalc(timestamp1, timestamp2, FormatTypes.MILLISECOND);
console.log(`Difference in Milliseconds: ${differenceInMilliseconds}`);

// To get the difference in Seconds
const differenceInSecond = timeDiffCalc(timestamp1, timestamp2, FormatTypes.SECOND);
console.log(`Difference in Seconds: ${differenceInSecond}`);

// To get the difference in Minutes
const differenceInMinutes = timeDiffCalc(timestamp1, timestamp2, FormatTypes.MINUTE);
console.log(`Difference in Minutes: ${differenceInMinutes}`);

// To get the difference in Hours (Approx.)
const differenceInHours = timeDiffCalc(timestamp1, timestamp2, FormatTypes.HOUR);
console.log(`Difference in Hours: ${differenceInHours}`);

// To get the difference in Day (Approx.)
const differenceInDays = timeDiffCalc(timestamp1, timestamp2, FormatTypes.DAY);
console.log(`Difference in Days: ${differenceInDays}`);

// To get the difference in Weeks (Approx.)
const differenceInWeeks = timeDiffCalc(timestamp1, timestamp2, FormatTypes.WEEK);
console.log(`Difference in Weeks: ${differenceInWeeks}`);

// To get the difference in Months (Approx.)
const differenceInMonths = timeDiffCalc(timestamp1, timestamp2, FormatTypes.MONTH);
console.log(`Difference in Months: ${differenceInMonths}`);

// To get the difference in Years (Approx.)
const differenceInYears = timeDiffCalc(timestamp1, timestamp2, FormatTypes.YEAR);
console.log(`Difference in Years: ${differenceInYears}`);

// To get the difference in DHMS (Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds)
const differenceInDHMS = timeDiffCalc(timestamp1, timestamp2, FormatTypes.DHMS);
console.log(`Difference in DHMS: ${differenceInDHMS}`);

// To get a detailed breakdown
const detailedDifference = timeDiffCalc(timestamp1, timestamp2, FormatTypes.DETAIL);
console.log(`Detailed difference: ${detailedDifference}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple deal to get the time difference.

```
var initialTime = new Date();
var finalTime = new Date();

console.log({
    days: finalTime.getDay() - initialTime.getDay(),
    hours: finalTime.getHours() - initialTime.getHours(),
    minutes: finalTime.getMinutes() - initialTime.getMinutes(),
    seconds: finalTime.getSeconds() - initialTime.getSeconds(),
    milliseconds: finalTime.getMilliseconds() - initialTime.getMilliseconds(),
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If `initialTime = '2022-01-01 01:00:00'` and `finalTime = '2022-01-08 02:00:00'`, the snippet outputs 1 hour while there are 25 hours. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/uLp9a5md/

Comment: This approach also has a bug in that any `finalTime` that is in the following day will have a day count of >0 regardless of whether the finalTime is 24 hours ahead of the `initial time`. I submitted an edit for this before realising this, and don't know how to remove my edit request, as the approach outlined in this answer is structually flawed.