# Difference Between 2 Timestamps using javascript without using moment.js

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I have 2 timestamps

```
var startTimestamp = 1488021704531;
var endTimestamp = 1488022516572;
```

I need the difference between these timestamps in hours and minutes using javascript but without using moment.js. 
Means the output should in hours and minutes like for ex:(02h 13min).

Comment: First convert it to date object something , new Date(1488022516572) etc after that write your logic

Comment: This is done with basic math. StackOverflow is not a code writing service or a tutorial service. Please explain problems you are having achieving your goal and show the code you have that isn't working as expected

Comment: @prince - please provide some more context or in depth information of the solution you have up to now. That said, I understand the need/question of your second part "hours/minutes/seconds".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between 2 timestamps using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767301/calculate-difference-between-2-timestamps-using-javascript)

Comment: @bRIMOs I already tried the solution given in your link but it didnt work it gives not the correct result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do provide some more context or in depth information of the solution you have up to now. That said, I understand the need/question of your second part "hours/minutes/seconds"; below is some context on that, or read up on it at [milliseconds to time in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763441/milliseconds-to-time-in-javascript).

That being said,

You could just either try subtracting, as in end - start.. as in following code example.

```js
    var startTimestamp = 1488021704531;
    var endTimestamp = 1488022516572;
    document.write(endTimestamp - startTimestamp + '<br/>');
```

This will output `812041` - which are the milliseconds.

If you want to convert those milliseconds to the known format of `hh:mm:ss.ms` you can try the following code by example - [also on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5dxnaLa/1/).

```js
    var startTimestamp = 1488021704531;
    var endTimestamp = 1488022516572;
    document.write(endTimestamp - startTimestamp + '<br/>');
    document.write(millisecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(endTimestamp - startTimestamp));
    
    document.write('<hr/>');
    
    function millisecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(ms) {
        var milliseconds = parseInt((ms%1000)/100)
            , seconds = parseInt((ms/1000)%60)
            , minutes = parseInt((ms/(1000*60))%60)
            , hours = parseInt((ms/(1000*60*60))%24);
    
        hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    
        return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
    }
```

Or read other solutions in this question: [milliseconds to time in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763441/milliseconds-to-time-in-javascript)

Comment: for the ones downvoting, it wouldn't hurt mentioning **why**. Helping out users is the main reason for this site, sure you can tell @prince to provide a bit more clarity, info on what he tried and what his code currently is doing etc - but you can slo try and help people out afterwards with some links & pointers in stead of leaving them in the cold. And if my answer is incorrect, do edit it or post **another** answer. I have no problem with that, silent downvotes just don't "add value".

Comment: Added a  +1. The answer in my vision is how it is supposed to be. Hopefully, it'll cancel out up to 5 downvotes.