# ReferenceError: performance is not defined when using performance.now()

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, performance.now

I am getting an error `ReferenceError: performance is not defined` when trying to use [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) to measure the execution time of a function call:

```
export async function find(someId: string, ctx: context.IContext) {

      try {
        var t0 = performance.now();

        var res = someModel.find(someId, ctx.cookies);

        var t1 = performance.now();
        console.log("Call to find took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");

        return res;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
      }
    }
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: where is performance defined? This is being done on client or server?

Comment: Are you using firefox-like browsers?

Comment: I am not defining it anywhere as I thought this is part of the standard library. Any help with how to do it? @Vatsal

I am on Google Chrome.

Comment: Strange.. I just made a sample program. It works for me http://jsbin.com/vowinaloni/edit?js,console,output

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute

Comment: @Vatsal Yeah that is weird  :(.

Comment: @Legends I have but that same thing ain't working for me somehow

Comment: try `window.performance`. I'm guessing typescript is trying to limit the scope of the performance variable when it compiles.

Answer (score 142):

I know this is tagged front-end but if anyone comes across this looking for a node.js solution (like me), you need to first require performance from the **perf_hooks** module (available in node 8.5+).

```
const {performance} = require('perf_hooks');
const t0 = performance.now();
...
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that `performance` is global in Node 16, but requires importing a module on older versions.

Answer (score 22):

Since the 'perf_hook' module exports multiple constructs (objects, functions, constants, etc.), you will need to explicitly specify which construct you wish to use. In this case, you need the `performance` construct. The declaration can be done in two ways:

```
const performance = require('perf_hooks').performance;
```

or

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks'); //object destructuring
```

Answer (score 15):

You will lose type information when using `require`, so the best way to import "performance" with TypeScript is using an `import` statement:

```
import {performance, PerformanceObserver} from 'perf_hooks';

const observer = new PerformanceObserver(items => items.getEntries().forEach((entry) => console.log(entry)));    
observer.observe({entryTypes: ['measure']});

performance.mark('start');
performance.mark('stop');
performance.measure('Measurement', 'start', 'stop');
```

Also make sure that you declared `@types/node` in your "dependencies" of "package.json".

Tested with TypeScript 4 & Node.js 14.

Answer (score 8):

yes! like above answers you need to add this..

```
const {
      performance,
      PerformanceObserver
    } = require('perf_hooks');
```

but you can run `performance.now()` inside your browser console or in your browser -> source tab -> snippet without adding above code.

you can read this to get to know more about this..

https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_now

Answer (score 3):

For me it was on pristine next.js project, right after running installation wizard and adding apollo. Updating NODE to latest version solved the problem.

You can do with with `nvm use 18` or by adding a `.nvmrc` file to the application.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why are people adding new answers about Node to a question tagged [frontend]?!?